# Node Postgres: How are key names constructed for a join query result

Tags: node.js, postgresql

The Node Postgres docs do not indicate what to expect for the key names in a query with joined tables.

Does anyone know if it would it be a concat of the table and column names, something like this:

```
[
  {
    "user.id": "100",
    "user.name": "james",
    "campaign.id": "5201",
    "campaign.budget": "5000"
  }
]
```

Or do you need to specifically alias each table name (below example assumes u/c to clear ambiguities, and `budget` is returned with no table prefix)?

```
[
  {
    "u.id": "100",
    "u.name": "james",
    "c.id": "5201",
    "budget": "5000"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, I am also using npm `pg` module, So maybe I can help here

If both the columns have the same i.e. table1 and table2 contains both a column `budget` then in the query you have to reference it by `table1.budget` and `table2.budget` but in the response, you will get `budget` as the column name.
**The response can contain of the budget value either of table1 or table2 with key name budget**

---

And if you refer the `budget column` without table name you will get an `error`, as Postgres will not know which table's budget to refer to.

---

If you want both of the column names then you can use aliases `AS`

```
SELECT table1.budget AS table1_budget,
table2.budget AS table2_budget, <other coulmns>
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON <Join Condition>
```

Comment: Thank you! If I don't use aliases, will the key names come back with dot syntax, eg `"user.id" "user.name"` etc?

Comment: it will come as `id` and `name`